# How does android get "android.app.SuperNotCalledException "?

Tags: android, exception

I'm curious about how android detects whether i called `super.onCreate` (or some other methods) in my `onCreate` method.

I guess it uses a flag and saw a flag `boolean mCalled;` in Activity.class, but not sure if it's for this detection. If it is, then it makes me confused because there are many supermethods to override but only one "mCalled" flag for those methods to detect if supermethod is called, seems impossible.

thx for reply~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern works like this:

```
private boolean superCalled;

private someFunction(...) {
    superCalled = false;
    someMethodThatRequiresSuperToBeCalled(...);
    if (!superCalled) {
        throw new SuperNotCalledException();
    }
}

protected void someMethodThatRequiresSuperToBeCalled(...) {
    superCalled = true;
}
```

If you go through the code, you'll find that the flag is used by the framework for only one method at a time. So even though there are many methods that require calls to `super.whatever()`, they can share the same flag.

Comment: do you mean that the IDE adds some codes in my overridden method implicitly?

Comment: @user1150712 - No. The pattern I posted is part of the framework code. Suppose you override `onCreate`. Just before the framework calls `onCreate` for your activity, it sets the `superCalled` flag to `false`. When the call returns, it checks whether the flag has been set to `true` and, if not`, throws the exception.

Comment: how can i find where is 'onCreate' called? I've tried ctrl+alt+h in eclipse, but that obviously not to work.

Comment: @user1150712 - You can find it in the [source for `Activity`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java). Look for the `performCreate` method. This actually is a bad example to use, because `performCreate` assumes that the flag has the default initial value of `false` (although you can see it being set in `Activity.onCreate`). Better examples are the other lifecycle methods (`performStart`/`onStart`, `performRestart`/`onRestart`, etc.)